# Apportioning employees based on top-down approach

Tags: r

Hope everyone's doing well!

I have 2 data.tables. One shows a selection of employees grouped by their job title and location.

```
library(data.table)
Staff <- c("Joe Bloggs", "John Smith", "Lois Walker", "Paula Diaz", "Charly Zhong", "Millie Michael")
Job_Title <- c("Manager", "Manager", "Junior", "Manager", "Junior", "Senior Associate")
Location <- c("Washington, DC", "New York", "New York", "New York", "Houston, TX")
Employees <- data.table(Staff, Job_Title, Location)
```

The other shows the cumulative FTE desired for each group.
It looks like so:

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
Job_Title <- c("Manager", "", "", "Senior Associate")
Location <- c("", "New York", "Houston, TX", "")
Cumulative_FTE_Desired <- c(6,5, 2, 3)
FTE <- data.table(Job_Title, Location, Cumulative_FTE_Desired)
FTE <- FTE %>%
  mutate(Adjusted_FTE = as.numeric(""))
```

I want to calculate the adjusted FTE column from the FTE table. To do this I need to apportion all staff from the first table based on what group they appear in and divide that by the Cumulative FTE Desired.

My goal is to have the Adjusted_FTE equal to 2 for the first option Managers as there are 3 managers, 5 for the second, i.e. exclude the 3 managers because they have already been included in the first option, 2 for the third and zero for the last because only one employee is a Senior Associate but they are already included in the Adjusted FTE calculation prior as being in Houston, TX.

Does anyone have a R solution to accomplish this? I've tried %in% and which via for loops but that requires a hierarchy. I do not want a hierarchy, I just want a top down approach i.e. assign FTE based on what group is targeted first in the FTE table and then exclude any employees matching that group from the second row's adjusted FTE calculation and so on.

Note: **any solution will work**, it does not have to be in data.table but that is my preferred option.

Thanks so much!

Comment: (1) Are you looking for a solution specific to the `data.table` package, or is that a mis-tag? (2) It really helps a lot when you provide data in a more consumable format: spaces make it a bit difficult to just "use" conventional copy/paste (and `read.*`). Please provide your sample data by [edit]ing your question and pasting the output from `dput(df)` (for each frame) in a [code block](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Thanks!

Comment: Data.table is what I've been using but if there's a better solution using other packages that will help too! I'll re-edit the code now.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect there will be more elegant ways to achieve this that I can't infer from the data you've provided (so seconding the first comment request), but based on my current understanding of your question this works with the data given as an example.

Note: `employees` is your first table, `FTE` is your second.

```
jobcrit <- FTE[!(is.na(JobTitle)), .(JobTitle, CumulativeFTE)]
loccrit <- FTE[!(is.na(Location)), .(Location, CumulativeFTE)]
jobFTE <- jobcrit[employees, on = .(JobTitle), nomatch = NULL][, AdjustedFTE := CumulativeFTE/.N, by = JobTitle][ , .(Staff, JobTitle, Location, AdjustedFTE)]
locFTE <- loccrit[(employees[!jobFTE, on = .(Staff)]), on = .(Location)][, AdjustedFTE := CumulativeFTE/.N, by = Location][ , .(Staff, JobTitle, Location, AdjustedFTE)]
employeeFTE <- rbind(jobFTE, locFTE)
rm(jobcrit, loccrit, jobFTE, locFTE)
```

Line by line:

1. Separate out where JobTitle has been specified in the FTE table
2. Separate out where Location has been specified in the FTE table
3. Join jobs criteria with a known desired FTE to employees with those jobs; calculate AdjustedFTE as (CumulativeFTE/rows in group) for the group "same job"
4. Join location criteria with to employees not covered in step #3, calculate the same AdjustedFTE grouped by location
5. Create a single data.table with those results.

Potential pitfalls:

- This assumes you will always want to check based on job title and then based on location. If you mean "appears first" row by row as opposed to column by column it may be more complicated.
- Creation of intermediate tables that will have to be removed may bother some people.
- You'll want to reorder the final result to suit whatever it is you prefer it to look like.

Recreated data used (locations shortened for convenience to me transcribing them):

```
structure(list(Staff = c("Joe Bloggs", "John Smith", "Lois Walker", 
"Pamela Diaz"), JobTitle = c("Manager", "Manager", "Junior", 
"Manager"), Location = c("DC", "NY", "NY", "NY"), row.names = c(NA, -4L
), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000029d70353130>, index = structure(integer(0), "`__JobTitle`" = c(3L, 
1L, 2L, 4L)))

structure(list(JobTitle = c("Manager", NA), Location = c(NA, 
"NY"), CumulativeFTE = c(6, 5)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000029d70353130>, index = structure(integer(0), "`__JobTitle`" = 2:1))
```

Final result:

```
structure(list(Staff = c("Joe Bloggs", "John Smith", "Pamela Diaz", 
"Lois Walker"), JobTitle = c("Manager", "Manager", "Manager", 
"Junior"), Location = c("DC", "NY", "NY", "NY"), AdjustedFTE = c(2, 
2, 2, 5)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000029d70353130>)
```

Comment: Perfect thanks so much Cyrus! I will update my code right now - but yes I don't want a hierarchy I'm looking for a top-down approach going row by row through the FTE table regardless of location or job title being first.

Comment: Glad to hear it! To clarify: you mean alternating between job title and location as needed in one row as opposed to parsing one column first and then the second? If you're able to add 1-2 more example rows to your FTE table that might help/I'd be happy to see if I can rewrite it as a function then.

Comment: Exactly thanks Cyrus! I'll add in a couple more rows now :)

Comment: Added in the rows thanks Cyrus!